# Difference in signature function between (int *) and (int [])?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, pointers, method-signature

I'm struggling a bit with pointers and how to properly declare the passing of an array in a function.

Could someone explain me the difference between this :

```
- (void) testFunction : (int *) array
{
    NSLog(@"%d",array[0]);
}
```

And this :

```
- (void) testFunction : (int []) array
{
    NSLog(@"%d",array[0]);
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1790720/611055 this will answer your question

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass an array in objective-c then write below, it is the proper way to pass an array

```
- (void) testFunction : (NSArray*) yourArray
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[yourArray objectAtIndex:0]);
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks, I know this. I don't know why I chosed Objective-C to illustrate this question, I better had simply chosen C. What I want to know is simply the difference between using * and [].

Comment: here * means value at pointer and [] is used for declaring an array. So according to me if you write [] in c it will be the proper way to declaring an array

Answer (score 0):

In the example given below,you are passing a pointer to an array which points to the first member of that array.So when you increment the pointer value, the position at which the pointer points to gets incremented..That is it points to the next item on the array.

```
 void testfunction(int *array)
  {
     printf("%d",*(array));        //value of array[0]
     printf("%d",*(array+1));      //value of array[1]
     printf("%d",*(array+2));      //value of array[2]


  }
```

In the example stated below,the value which the pointer holds is getting changed,not the position.

```
void testfunction(int *array)
  {
     printf("%d",*(array));    //value of array[0] gets printed
     printf("%d",*(array)+1);  // value of array[0]+1
     printf("%d",*(array)+2);  //value of array[0]+2


  }
```

The example given below is similar to first example. array[0] denotes value present in the first location.The index value represent the position to which the pointer array has to point to .Second print statement increments the value in the 0th position.The third print statement increment the position at which the pointer array points to.That is,it takes the next value in the array.

```
  void testfunction(int array[])
  {
     printf("%d",array[0]);       //value of array[0]
     printf("%d",array[0]+1);     //value of array[0] +1
     printf("%d",array[0+1]);     // value of array[1].Index value changed
  }
```

Sorry for using C Syntax.Thought it could be easily explained this way .
Hope it Helps!!!