# Passing array as an argument

Tags: c

I know these two are equivalent:

`int some_function(char n[])`

and

`int some_function(char *n)`

is there any reason to prefer one over the other??

Comment: Maybe someone thought you haven't done enough research?
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_passing_arrays_to_functions.htm

Comment: um sorry I did search but I used the wrong terms I think. you can close this if you want to as the other answer is nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On seeing

```
int some_function(char n[])
```

compiler interprets it as

```
int some_function(char *n)
```

Both are same. First one prefer over second sometimes to let the other programmers know that an array is passed (i.e, pointer to array element) to the function.

Comment: if anyone else searches, this is also good: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790704/difference-between-square-brackets-and-asterisk