# What is the difference between A and A[] in function parameter?

Tags: c++, parameters

```
//function prototype at the top
void fillRandArray(int A[], int number, int maxNum);

//function declaration
void fillRandArray(int* A, int number, int maxNum) {
   for(int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
      A[i] = rand() % maxNum + 1; 
   }
}

int A[MAX_STUDENTS];

fillRandArray(A, number, 44);
```

I dont understand the code, so the prototype set `int A[]`
then the declaration set `int* A`

when we pass the argument, shouldn't we pass like this...

```
fillRandArray(A[MAX_STUDENTS], number, 44); <---- ???
```

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790704/difference-between-square-brackets-and-asterisk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below is passing the name of an array, which is an address.

```
void fillRandArray(int A[], int number, int maxNum);
```

The code below this is passing just the name of an address, which happens to be A in this case.  They are basically doing the same thing.

```
void fillRandArray(int* A, int number, int maxNum)
```

You would not pass the argument like the following:

```
fillRandArray(A[MAX_STUDENTS],..., ...);
```

because you told the compiler to expect an address, not an element of the array.  So you would just pass it A (i.e. the name of array, which is also the starting address).  So it would look like this:

```
fillRandArray(A, number, 44);
```

Ask more questions, if I didn't explain it well enough.

Comment: Thanks,so array is passed by reference? Because it does not need *

Comment: Yes, I believe arrays are passed by reference in C++.  Reference meaning a reference to the actual array (i.e. well address) is passed to the function as opposed to being passed by value, which would just be a copy.  If you didn't want the array to be changed in your function, you could always put const in front of the array.

Comment: The name of an array is __not__ an address.

Comment: @MrPickle5 The only time C++ passes anything by reference is when you declare a parameter to be a reference.  C++ doesn't allow passing C style arrays at all (since C didn't).  So you can either declare the function to take a pointer, and count on the implicit array to pointer conversion (to be avoided if at all possible), or you can declare a reference to the array.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that C-style arrays can't be passed as arguments
to a function.  When you write `int a[]` as a parameter in
a function, the compiler translates it to `int* a`.  In
addition, if you provide a dimension (e.g. `int a[10]`), it is
simply ignored.

Also, an array can convert to a pointer, and will do so in a lot
of contexts.  This is what happens in `fillRandArray(A, number,
44)`; the array `A` is implicitly converting to a pointer.

As for `fillRandArray(a[MAX_STUDENTS], number, 44)`, this
indexes into the array for the first element; with your
declaration, it passes an `int` (not an array or a pointer),
except that it accesses one beyond the end of the array, so it's
undefined behavior.

In general, you want to avoid this (although with `main`, you
can't): the function should either take an `std::vector<int>&
a`, or in a few special cases, an `int (&a)[N]` (in which case,
the function should be a template, and `N` be a template
parameter).  So you might write:

```
template <size_t N>
void fillRandArray( int (&a)[N], int maxNumber )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i != N; ++ i ) {
        a[i] = rand() % maxNum + 1;
    }
}
```

(But for this sort of thing, `std::vector` is far preferrable.)