# How to pass char as function argument in class?

Tags: c++, class, char

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class X{
    private:
        char ime[50];
    X(char *c){ // or char (char c[]) which one to use?
        // how to set the value of c inside the ime[50];
    }
};

int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

I want to pass a char as a function argument inside the constructor of a Class, so I can use two ways.. which one do I use? And once the value is passed, how do I put the value of c inside the char ime[50] variable of the class?

Comment: Use an `std::string` instead. Otherwise you will have to worry about the length of the thing being passed.

Comment: ... or use `std::vector<char>` - depends what you need.

Comment: @juanchopanza It's for an exercise which specifies that I should use a char, with a specified maximum length.

Comment: OK, then you have to ensure you do not copy more then 50 characters, bearing in mind that character strings "a.k.a. c-strings" are nul terminated, i.e. their end is marked by a `'\0'` character. Whether your function parameter is `char*` or `char[]` is cosmetic.

Comment: Why are you adding "using namespace std"? it's a bad habit.

Answer (score 2):

As the comment suggested, the easiest way to use `std::string`. Also, if your constructor is not `public` nobody can call it.

```
class X{
    private:
        std::string ime;
    public:
        X(const std::string& str) : ime(str) {
        }
};
```

If you insist on using `char*` though, and you are *sure* that you will **only ever** pass in a character array of length `50`, you can use `memcpy`.

```
class X{
    private:
        char ime[50];
    public:
        X(const char* c) {
            memcpy(ime,c,50);
        }
};
```

If you insist on `char*` **and** you do not know how long the length is (only that it is less than `50`), you will have to pass in the length.

```
class X{
    private:
        char ime[50];
    public:
        X(const char* c, int length) {
            if (length > 50) length = 50;
            memcpy(ime,c,length);
        }
};
```

Note that we use `memcpy` instead of `strncpy` because I am making no assumptions about what is inside your `char[]`.

Comment: @merlin2011 why isn't "str" const ref?

Comment: @hellfire769, Correcting. Too hasty. :)

Comment: Why can't I call the object for example X x("hfsfasdasfsdsa"), it says that (char*) is private?

Comment: @user3659335, That's strange. Let me check.

Comment: @user3659335, You will have to give me a reproducible example. I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: @user3659335, Read the second sentence of my answer, and observe that my code has `public:` before the constructor but yours does not.

Comment: @user3659335, Also, remember that the second form should only be used if you pass exactly `50` characters.

Comment: @merlin2011 Thanks, works well now. Just one last question if you don't mind, how do I make a function that returns the value of ime inside the clas?

Comment: @user3659335, You are welcome. Please mark this as the accepted answer if it resolved your question.

Comment: @user3659335, The function would have to return a dynamically allocated array (using `malloc`) which is a copy of the original array, because you cannot really return an **array** from a C function.

Comment: @user3659335, It would return a pointer to this `malloc`ed array.

Answer (score 0):

Both are the same, use C string copy routines to copy the data into the internal buffer.

pay close attention to the length of the string passed in, and copy only the first 50 characters.

But indeed, using std (string or vector, basic_str) is much more simple/safe to use

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that you have to take into consideration:

1. As others (merlin2011, juanchopanza) suggested above, if the argument is a null-terminated string, you are better off using std::string, and then using a copy routine such as std::copy to fill the data member array.
2. You should pass the argument as const, as it is not being modified within the constructor's body (that is).
3. If you are passing an array of char values (rather than a null-terminated string), you should pass the array's size as another argument to the constructor. Then, inside the constructor's body, use a copy routine (such as std::copy) to copy the the required amount of char values (as specified by the additional argument) to the data member array.
4. In this case, there is no difference between the char* or char[] notation, as they will both specify a char pointer parameter that is being passed to a function. For more info about the difference between these notations, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790704/difference-between-square-brackets-and-asterisk).