# Template parameter not working in constructor with single typename for same datatypes

Tags: c++, templates

While experimenting with `std::forward`, wrote a simple `person` class which has just `name` and `address` and a constructor which initializes them. Below is the class definition.

```
class person {
   std::string name;
   std::string address;
public:

template<class T1, class T2>
   person(T1&& _name, T2&& _address) : name{ std::forward<T1>(_name) }, 
   address{ std::forward<T2>(_address) } { std::cout << "Template Constructor" << std::endl; }

 // This is not working if passed by rvalue
template<class T>
 person(T&& _name, T&& _address) : name{ std::forward<T>(_name) }, address{ std::forward<T>(_address) } { std::cout << "Single template Constructor" << std::endl; }

};
int main(){

    person p{"john doe","Somewhere"}; // This doesn't work without the template constructor which takes two typenames
    std::string name="user";
    std::string address = "blah";

    person p2{name, address}; // This of course works with just template<class T>.
}
```

Intellisense is showing error as `no constructor of "person" can take two arguments "const char[9], const char[10]"` without the `template<class T1, class T2>`. Why isn't this taking as just "const char[]" and work with `template<class T>`? Is there a way to make just `template<class T>` work in this case?

Comment: Don't work off intellisense.  Work off actual compiler messages.   Intellisense may be right, but don't post intellisense messages in your question, post compiler messages.  What happens when you actually compile it?

Comment: On top of that, the code you posted doesn't compile - it has non-sensical parts in the second constructor.   Please post an [mcve]

Comment: You *probably* want to just be taking either two char const *'s or two std::string const &'s.   A const char[10] is a specific length and strings of different lengths won't match it.

Comment: Godbolt compiles fine after fixing your move ctor: https://godbolt.org/g/i3UH2E

Comment: @xaxxon, edited the code and it should compile now. as is

Comment: What is the purpose of using a template constructor here?

Comment: @super to take the arguments as lvalue or rvalue, depending on how they are passed, and do a perfect forwarding, instead of overloading constructors. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward

Comment: @xaxxon that would work taking char * or const string&, but I'm trying to understand why the template takes size after resolving to `const char[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have this:

```
template <typename T>
void fn(T&&) {
  // ...
}

int main(int, char**) {
  fn("abc");

  return 0;
}
```

It seems to me that you're expecting `T` to resolve to `const char []` or `const char *` ([which in this context can be considered the same type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790704/difference-between-square-brackets-and-asterisk)). Actually, `T` resolves to `const char (&) [4]`, retaining the size information. Which is why you can't use your single template constructor with two C-strings of different size.

If you try to call the single template constructor with two C-strings of the same size you'll see that it works.