# How to make dynamic int array

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

I have trouble getting my dynamic int array to work properly. I have tried some examples but still can not get it to work. I think I am doing a minor pointer problem but I cannot figure out what. I want to have a dynamic int array and then from another function add numbers to this array. I have gotten the counter to work.

I have tried putting `*` at different places and trying my way but I am at this point lacking the knowledge to actually know where the `*` should be. I know some basics about `&` and `*` but apparently not enough

```
static void counterFunction(int* pointerToArray[], int* count)
{
    while (*count < 10) {
        *(*pointerToArray + *count) = *count;
        *count = *count + 1;
    }
}

static int* writeSortedToArray(void)
{
    // I need to store 1000 numbers at this point
    int* dynamicArray = malloc(1000 * sizeof(int));
    int counter = 0;

    counterFunction(&dynamicArray, &counter);

    return 0;
}
```

The counter works properly, the dynamic array does not work at all. It only store a 0 according to my debugger (xcode)

Comment: Too many `*`, `static void counterFunction(int* pointerToArray, int* count)` enought and `while (*count<10) {
    *(pointerToArray+*count)=*count;
    *count=*count+1;
 }`

Comment: Ahh and add `free(dynamicArray)` before end of program

Comment: I then get `Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'int *' from 'int'; remove *`

And the array turn into NULL after first loop

Comment: Unable to reproduce your issue. It's printing 10 elements when I tried to print the contents of `dynamicArray` in a `for` loop terminating when variable reaches `counter` value.

Comment: Can you make the program that you posted more complete? How are you calling the functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make some mistakes:

1) `int* pointerToArray[]` is a pointer to pointer(s). You should use `int* pointerToArray`.

2) `*(*pointerToArray+*count)=*count;` is dereferencing `pointerToArray` two times, you should use `*(pointerToArray + *count) = *count;`.

3) `dynamicArray`is already a pointer, you should not use the `&`operator to get its address. Then `counterFunction(&dynamicArray, &counter);`should be converted in `counterFunction(dynamicArray, &counter);`.

Finally, your code should look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void counterFunction(int * pointerToArray, int * count){

    while (*count < 10) {
        *(pointerToArray + *count) = *count;
        *count += 1;
    }
}


static int * writeSortedToArray(){

    //I need to store 1000 numbers at this point
    int * dynamicArray = malloc(100 * sizeof(int));
    int counter = 0;

    counterFunction(dynamicArray, &counter);

    // as suggested, finally release the array
    free(dynamicArray);

    return 0;
}

int main(){
    writeSortedToArray();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int *pointerToArray`? That's nonsense.  That's just pointerToInt

Comment: why would you `return 0;` instead of `void`?

Comment: The way he used to initialise an array is nosense, I only tried to make him understand the way pointers work. `int [] pointerToArray` may be smarter but does the same things as `int *pointerToArray`. I used `return 0` to be consistent with his code, maybe that function was not complete yet.

Comment: The thing is you shouldn't call `pointerToArray` something which is not a pointer to an array, which can only be `int (*pointerToArray)[]`

Comment: You changed the return type from an `int *` to an `int`. That's not being consistent.

Comment: The return type was a typo.

Comment: My `pointerToArray` is used as a pointer to an array. There is no real difference between the two notations. I obviously couldn't have used `int (*pointerToArray)[]`.

Comment: No it is not being used as a pointer to an array. You could call it `pointerToFirstElementOfAnArray` :). As I said, the only thing that IS a pointer to an array is this: `int (*tmp)[]`

Comment: This can also be used as a pointer to an array: `int **tmp`, but definitely not your thing.

Comment: An array is simply a pointer to the first element of the array itself. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790704/difference-between-square-brackets-and-asterisk

Comment: First, they are not the same, they only look the same when they are parameters of a function, which is the case now, so that's ok. BUT, what I'm telling you is that a pointer to an array is NOT the same as a pointer to the first element of an array; they are completely different. Here you have a pointer to the first element of an array, not a pointer to an array. I already showed you what a pointer to an array looks like (and a pointer to a pointer to an int, which can mimic a pointer to an array)

Comment: @LucaDiLiello Better stop. You're only talking yourself into trouble. An array is not a pointer and pointer is not an array. With your logic for `int a[10];` the expressions `a + 1;` and `&a + 1;` would be the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the other answers, I'd suggest a more generic approach and encapsulation of the management logic:

```c
#include <assert.h>   // assert()
#include <stddef.h>   // size_t
#include <stdbool.h>  // bool, true, false
#include <stdlib.h>   // malloc(), calloc(), free(), EXIT_FAILURE, EXIT_SUCCESS
#include <stdio.h>    // fputs(), printf(), putchar()

typedef int value_type;
char const *conversion_specifier  = "%d"
size_t const initial_capacity     =  10
size_t growth_factor              =   2

typedef struct dynarray_tag {
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
    value_type *data;
} dynarray_t;

dynarray_t dynarray_create(void)
{
    dynarray_t new_dynarray = { 0, 0, NULL };
    return new_dynarray;
}

dynarray_t dynarray_create_reserve(size_t capacity)
{
    dynarray_t new_dynarray = { 0, capacity, NULL };
    new_dynarray.data = malloc(capacity * sizeof *new_dynarray.data);
    return new_dynarray;
}

dynarray_t dynarray_create_size(size_t size)
{
    dynarray_t new_dynarray = { size, size, NULL };
    new_dynarray.data = calloc(size, sizeof *new_dynarray.data);
    return new_dynarray;
}

bool dynarray_is_valid(dynarray_t const *dynarray)
{
    if (!dynarray)
        return false;

    if (!dynarray->size && !dynarray->capacity && !dynarray->data)
        return true;

    if (dynarray->size > dynarray->capacity)
        return false;

    if (dynarray->capacity && dynarray->data)
        return true;

    return false;
}

size_t dynarray_get_size(dynarray_t const *dynarray)
{
    assert(dynarray_is_valid(dynarray));
    return dynarray->size;
}

size_t dynarray_get_capacity(dynarray_t const *dynarray)
{
    assert(dynarray_is_valid(dynarray));
    return dynarray->capacity;
}

value_type* dynarray_at(dynarray_t *dynarray, size_t position)
{
    assert(dynarray_is_valid(dynarray) && dynarray->size && position < dynarray->size);
    return &dynarray->data[position];
}

value_type* dynarray_front(dynarray_t *dynarray)
{
    assert(dynarray_is_valid(dynarray));
    return dynarray_at(dynarray, 0);
}

value_type* dynarray_back(dynarray_t *dynarray)
{
    assert(dynarray_is_valid(dynarray));
    return dynarray_at(dynarray, dynarray->size - 1);
}

bool dynarray_reserve(dynarray_t *dynarray, size_t new_capacity)
{
    assert(dynarray_is_valid(dynarray));

    if (new_capacity <= dynarray->capacity)
        return true;

    if (new_capacity < dynarray->size)
        return false;

    value_type *new_data = realloc(dynarray->data, new_capacity * sizeof *new_data);
    if (!new_data)
        return false;

    dynarray->data = new_data;
    dynarray->capacity = new_capacity;

    return true;
}

bool dynarray_resize(dynarray_t *dynarray, size_t new_size)
{
    assert(dynarray_is_valid(dynarray));

    if (new_size <= dynarray->capacity)
        return true;

    value_type *new_data = realloc(dynarray->data, new_size * sizeof *new_data);
    if (!new_data)
        return false;

    dynarray->data = new_data;
    dynarray->size = new_size;
    dynarray->capacity = new_size;

    return true;
}

bool dynarray_insert(dynarray_t *dynarray, size_t position, value_type value)
{
    assert(dynarray_is_valid(dynarray));

    if (dynarray->size + 1 > dynarray->capacity) {
        size_t new_capacity = dynarray->capacity ? dynarray->capacity * growth_factor : initial_capacity;
        if (!dynarray_reserve(dynarray, new_capacity))
            return false;
    }

    for (size_t i = dynarray->size; i > position; --i)
        dynarray->data[i] = dynarray->data[i - 1];

    dynarray->data[position] = value;
    dynarray->size++;

    return true;
}

bool dynarray_push_front(dynarray_t *dynarray, value_type value)
{
    assert(dynarray_is_valid(dynarray));
    return dynarray_insert(dynarray, 0, value);
}

bool dynarray_push_back(dynarray_t *dynarray, value_type value)
{
    assert(dynarray_is_valid(dynarray));
    return dynarray_insert(dynarray, dynarray->size, value);
}

bool dynarray_insert_sorted(dynarray_t *dynarray, value_type value)
{
    assert(dynarray_is_valid(dynarray));

    if (!dynarray_get_size(dynarray) || value < *dynarray_front(dynarray))
        return dynarray_push_front(dynarray, value);

    if (value > *dynarray_back(dynarray))
        return dynarray_push_back(dynarray, value);

    size_t insert_pos = 0;
    for (; insert_pos < dynarray->size && value > dynarray->data[insert_pos]; ++insert_pos);
    return dynarray_insert(dynarray, insert_pos, value);
}

void dynarray_print(dynarray_t const *dynarray)
{
    assert(dynarray_is_valid(dynarray));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < dynarray->size; ++i) {
        printf(conversion_specifier, dynarray->data[i]);
        if (i + 1 < dynarray->size)
            printf(", ");
    }
}

void dynarray_sort(dynarray_t *dynarray)  // insertion sort
{
    assert(dynarray_is_valid(dynarray));

    for (size_t i = 1; i < dynarray->size; i++) {
        value_type key = dynarray->data[i];

        size_t k = i - 1;
        for (; k >= 0 && dynarray->data[k] > key; --k)
            dynarray->data[k + 1] = dynarray->data[k];

        dynarray->data[k + 1] = key;
    }
}

void dynarray_free(dynarray_t *dynarray)
{
    assert(dynarray_is_valid(dynarray));

    free(dynarray->data);
    dynarray->size = dynarray->capacity = 0;
    dynarray->data = NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    dynarray_t arr = dynarray_create();

    if (!dynarray_is_valid(&arr)) {
        fputs("Not enough memory. :(\n\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int result = EXIT_FAILURE;

    for (value_type i = 2; i < 15; i += 2) {
        if (!dynarray_push_back(&arr, i))
            goto error_exit;
    }
    dynarray_print(&arr);
    putchar('\n');

    for (value_type i = 1; i < 14; i += 2) {
        if (i != 7) {
            if (!dynarray_push_front(&arr, i))
                goto error_exit;            
        }
    }
    dynarray_print(&arr);
    putchar('\n');

    dynarray_sort(&arr);
    dynarray_print(&arr);
    putchar('\n');

    if (!dynarray_insert_sorted(&arr, 0))
        goto error_exit;
    dynarray_print(&arr);
    putchar('\n');

    if (!dynarray_insert_sorted(&arr, 15))
        goto error_exit;
    dynarray_print(&arr);
    putchar('\n');

    if (!dynarray_insert_sorted(&arr, 7))
        goto error_exit;
    dynarray_print(&arr);
    putchar('\n');

    result = EXIT_SUCCESS;

error_exit:
    result == EXIT_FAILURE && fputs("Not enough memory. :(\n\n", stderr);
    dynarray_free(&arr);
    return result;
}
```

---

#### Output:

```
2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14
13, 11, 9, 5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
```

---

#### Todo:

- `dynarray_insert_range()`
- `dynarray_create_init()` from iterator pair
- `dynarray_from_file()`
- `dynarray_copy()`
- `dynarray_begin()`
- `dynarray_end()`
- ...

Answer (score 0):

```
static void counterFunction(int array[], int* count)
{
        ptrdiff_t i;

        for (i = *count; i < 10; i++)
                array[i] = i;
        *count = i;
}

static int *writeSortedToArray(void)
{
        //I need to store 1000 numbers at this point
        int *dynamicArray;
        int counter;

        dynamicArray = calloc(sizeof(*dynamicArray) * 1000);
        counter = 0;
        counterFunction(dynamicArray, &counter);
        /* counter == 10 */

        return dynamicArray;
}
```

First of all, if a function always returns 0, it should be `void` (except `main()`, for its own reasons).  Although you probably didn't want to `return 0`, and instead `return` the array.

The counter function doesn't need to know that the array is dynamic. It can just accept any array, and use it with array notation.

I changed to a `for` loop, because it's more natural.

You don't need to pass a pointer to the array, and in fact you shouldn't, because then the compiler could notice the difference between a pointer to an array and a pointer to a pointer, and complain.

I don't get the purpose of your code, but this code is just the corrected version of your code.

Remember to `free(dynamicArray);` at some point.

Answer (score -1):

Wrong use of pointer here. Your Dynamicarray from the WriteSortedToArray is already an adress so you do not need to pass it as an adress.
This should work :

```
static void counterFunction(int* pointerToArray, int count){

while (count < 10)
{
    pointerToArray[count] = count;
    count++;
 }
}


static int* writeSortedToArray(void){

int* dynamicArray = malloc(1000 * sizeof(int));
int counter = 0;

counterFunction(dynamicArray, counter);

return 0;
}
```

If you want to keep the value of your counter when exiting your counterFunction which is 10, do this instead :

```
static void counterFunction(int* pointerToArray, int *count){

while (*count < 10)
{
    pointerToArray[*count] = *count;
    *count++;
 }
}


static int* writeSortedToArray(void){

int* dynamicArray = malloc(1000 * sizeof(int));
int counter = 0;

counterFunction(dynamicArray, &counter);

return 0;
}
```

You should always free your memory using the free function to avoid memory leak issues.

```
free(dynamicArray)
```

Comment: I sense global variables and a some misplaced `}`s.

Comment: Explain yourselves ?

Comment: `int *pointerToArray`? That's nonsense.  That's just pointerToInt

Comment: if a function always returns 0, it should be `void` (except `main()`, for its own reasons).  Although you probably didn't want to `return 0`, and instead `return` the array.

Comment: Even if you are right, The question wasnt about it. but we can assume the int* was intended for returning the array later on.